# Powershell 5.0 Compress-archive creates empty file duplicates of some folders

Tags: powershell, compression, 7zip

Long story short, I have a powershell script which compresses several folders into zip-files. 
In order to compress a single directory into a zip file, I use this command:

`Compress-Archive -Path $SourcePath -DestinationPath $OutputPath -CompressionLevel Optimal`

Where `$SourcePath` is an absolute path ending on *, e.g. `C:\Build\Output*`, and `$OutputPath` is an absolute path ending on .zip, e.g. `C:\Build\Debug.zip`.

There are a lot of files and folders in the source path.

The issue I experience is that, scattered around the zip file, folders have a duplicate empty file. This causes problems when trying unzip the archive with e.g. 7-zip.

Interestingly enough, I do not see this issue with the build-in unzip in Total Commander.

I am wondering if this is an issue with the Powershell command, or 7-zip?

Comment: It creates empty file for every folder that does not contain files. I assume ZipArchiveHelper has a bug (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/Modules/Shared/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1#L701).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have found a work-around, but no solution :)

Comment: Issue link: https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/27

Comment: Fantastic issue description, much better than what I could have done myself. Thank you.